# space of connections is an affine space

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

> The space of connections on a principal $G$-bundle $E_G$ over the
>   groupoid $\mathbb{X}=[X_1\rightrightarrows X_0]$ is an affine space
>   for the space of all $\text{ad}(E_G)$-valued $1$-forms on the groupoid
>   $\mathbb{X}=[X_1\rightrightarrows X_0]$.

Above statement is mentioned with out mentioning in what sense it is affine space.

Can some one spell out what does it mean to say? I am not asking for proof. Just the meaning of the above sentence..

In case you are not ok with Groupoids, read it as

> The space of connections on a principal $G$-bundle $E_G$ over the
>   manifold $M$ is an affine space for the space of all $\text{ad}(E_G)$-valued $1$-forms on the manifold $M$.

Can some one tell me what this statement mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that, by  "The space of connections on a principal $G$-bundle $E_G$ over the
 manifold $M$ is an affine space for the space of all $\text{ad}(E_G)$-valued $1$-forms on the manifold $M$" it means the following:

> Given two connection $1$-forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ on $E_G\rightarrow M$, the difference $\omega_1-\omega_2$ gives a $\text{ad}(P)$-valued $1$-form  on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

This means, if you fix a connection $a$. You can write any other connection $b=a+c$ where $c$ is the pullback to $E_G$ of an $ad(E_G) $ invariant 1 form by the projection map $E_G\rightarrow M$ and this correspondence is bijective.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something here.. What is $\text{ad}(E_G)$ "invariant" $1$ form? I read it in hurry as $\text{ad}(E_G)$ "valued" $1$ form and upvoted.. Now I am confused...

Comment: I thought what you are saying is as follows : For connection  $1$-forms $\omega,\omega':E_G\rightarrow \Lambda^1_{\mathfrak{g}}T^*E_G$ on $E_G$, the difference $\omega-\omega'$, which is a $1$-form on $E_G$ is a pullback of a $1$-form, say $\tau$, on $M$ along the map $\pi:E_G\rightarrow M$... That is, $\omega-\omega'=\pi^*(\tau)$... Moreover, this $\tau$ on $M$ is expected to have some extra structure..